# How to select all rows from table?

Tags: slick

As subject says, how to query a table without condition (WHERE clause)?

For example, LookupTable.filter(r => true) (this doesn't work of course)

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically what you need to do is to use this:`LookupTable.result`.

In fact this is exactly one of the first code samples in Slick documentation "Getting started section" here: http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.1/gettingstarted.html#querying

As there is no code pasted in your question I can only assume that you are aware of that you need to use `db.run(...)` to fire you `DBIO` (generated by this `result` call).

Comment: I have this configuration `val Roles: TableQuery[RoleTable] = TableQuery[RoleTable]` for my slick table and there is no `result` method at `Roles.result`. The docs do not seem to have changed... What could I be missing?

Comment: Which Slick version?

Comment: The problem was this missing import `import slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile.api._`